# Understanding this proof of directional derivative

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

> **Exercise 5.1.** Suppose that $f'(\mathbf{a};\mathbf{u})$ exists and
> $$f'(\mathbf{a};\mathbf{u})=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{a})}{t}=\lambda.$$
> If $c\ne0$, then
> \begin{align*}
> f'(\mathbf{a};c\mathbf{u}) & =\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+tc\mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{a})}{t}=c\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+tc\mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{a})}{ct}=\\
> & =c\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+h\mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{a})}{h}=c\lambda,
> \end{align*}
> so $f'(\mathbf{a};c\mathbf{u})$ exists and equals $cf'(\mathbf{a};\mathbf{u})$.

I just have a question about the last step where we replace taking the limit of $t$ to the limit of $h$. It does make perfect sense that as $t$ approaches $0$, $h=ct$ approaches $0$, but what is the rigorous justification for being able to change what variable we are taking the limit to $0$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=a$. Take $t\ne0$; you want to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}f(tx)=a$. Take $\varepsilon>0$; you want to prove that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies|f(tx)-a|<\varepsilon$. Just take $\delta'>0$ such that $|x|<\delta'\implies|f(x)-a|<\varepsilon$ and then take $\delta=\frac{\delta'}{|t|}$. Then$$|x|<\delta\iff|tx|<|t|\delta=\delta'\implies|f(tx)-a|<\varepsilon.$$